# After update to Webpack 5. No output file is created.I got the error like with Webpack 4, but no output file

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I've updated to version 5. I'm using the webpack-cli like before. I'm using typescript and the ts-loader. After compiling I got this message:  "webpack 5.4.0 compiled with 128 errors in 13540 ms". This are the same errors like I had in webpack 4.Some not defined or not typed variables.

```
ERROR in C:\Users\mhueb\Documents\Entwicklung\Projekte\nodeapps\libs\es\website\server\routes.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\mhueb\Documents\Entwicklung\Projekte\nodeapps\libs\es\website\server\routes.ts(99,37)
      TS2339: Property 'tagdddd' does not exist on type 'ITag'.

ERROR in C:\Users\mhueb\Documents\Entwicklung\Projekte\nodeapps\libs\es\xd\es2dGui.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\mhueb\Documents\Entwicklung\Projekte\nodeapps\libs\es\xd\es2dGui.ts(795,17)
      TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'CanvasTextBaseline'.
```

But the difference is that webpack 4 build an usable output file. But webpack 5 doesn't. No output file. All errors looks like the same, I can't recognize what error is the problem. Is there something like an error level I can set? Or could be updated ts-loader version the a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. TS-Loader was the problem. You can set a loader option:

```
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true
            }
          }
```